# Does Kubeflow helps to run ML in a distributed manner

Tags: machine-learning, apache-spark-ml, kubeflow

I am going through Kubeflow documentation for couple of days and can anyone help me to answer the below questions.

1. Does Kubeflow helps to run any ML algorithm in a distributed manner?
2. What's the difference between Kubeflow and Spark ML?

Answer (score 2):

**Kubflow** is a set of services that leverage Kubernetes distribution to perform ML related workloads. [**TFJob**](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/training/tftraining/) is Kubernetes resource provided by Kubeflow that runs distributed Tensorflow jobs.

**Kubeflow** include other services such as **Kubeflow Pipelines** that do orchestration of any kind of workflows and it's mainly designed for ML workloads.

**Spark ML** is a software library that leverages Apache Spark to run distributed ML algorithms, usually classic ml algorithms. Apache Spark is a platform for distributed computing that can be deployed in Kubernetes or Hadoop clusters (or locally) and it does not run distributed deep learning (tensorflow), or at least no designed for.